# I can't display many forms in one panel

Tags: c#, forms

I wanted to make a list of forms in my panel, but i don't know why i can only display one.

```
List<body_gallery> bgs = bg.listOfPhotos();

            foreach (body_gallery p in bgs)
            {
                gallery.Add(new SmallPhoto(p) { TopLevel = false, TopMost = true });
            }

            foreach (var i in gallery)
            {
                galleryPanel.Controls.Add(i);
                i.Show();
            }
```

I am sure that gallery has 4 elements but i can't tell why i can only see 1.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaNxK.png

Comment: They are probably all there but in the same position, so you can only see one of them.

Answer (score -1):

I managed it. I used simple panel rather than FlowLayoutPanel. Thanks for all commenting, i will remember your advices!